# Color / image behind a view with elastic scrolling?

Tags: objective-c, macos, safari, nsscrollview, nscolor

How can I set the image "behind" the view when elastic scrolling kicks in?

By default it's just white, I'd like to set it to a color or an image- like how Safari has linen behind its' WebView and so on.

Comment: do you mean to add image in background of view or scrollview ?

Comment: An image or color in the elastic area behind the scrollview- like the linen behind Safari's webview when you scroll up or down too far.

Comment: I didn't get what you are trying to explain. I try to drag the view of safari it just shows the dark gray back ground only.

Comment: Safari 6 is linen, it might be dark gray in an older version. That's what I'm trying to set- the area that shows when you're doing elastic scrolling.

Comment: I think you can set the background of the container controller's view for that with any image or color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I'm currently doing this in my app is just by adding a big `UIImageView` behind the scroll view in my view controller.

I spent a while messing around with the background image property on table views and stuff but I encountered a lot of weirdness when I changed the `contentInset`/`contentOffset` if I did it that way.